# hg log timezone formatting

Tags: date, timezone, mercurial

For `hg`, I can set formatting with `--template` key to output only date, like this:

```
> hg log -l1 --template "{date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\n"  
2016-10-07 10:22:41
```

I can use `%z` control to output timezone offset:

```
> hg log -l1 --template "{date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')}\n"
2016-10-07 10:22:41 +0300
```

Also, in OpenSuse `date` realization there is `%:::z` control for more readable format:

```
> date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %:::z'
2016-10-07 11:03:34 +03
```

It's not POSIX control, but is there a way to achieve something like this in `hg log` formatting? Simple way is not working:

```
> hg log -l1 --template "{date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %:::z')}\n"  
2016-10-07 10:22:41 %:::z
```

From `man date`:

> %:::z numeric time zone with : to necessary precision (e.g., -04, +05:30)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isodate filter seems like the closest to what you want.

```
$ hg log -r1 --template 'date: {date|isodate}\n'
date: 2009-05-05 06:55 +0000
```

> isodate: date keyword. Render the date as a text string in ISO 8601
>   format. Yields a string like “2006-09-04 15:13:13 -0700”.

To condense the timezone doesn't appear to be feasible. It's even mentioned in this SO Q&A titled: [Stripping hg date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381107/stripping-hg-date).

Therefore I think you're best option will be to enlist the help using `sed` or `awk` to cleanup the output to suit your needs.

#### References

- http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html
- http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html#sec:template:filter